# Wordpress Woocommerce Product grid equal row height

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm creating a website using WordPress with Woocommerce plugin. I need to display product page, product title and product short description in product category layout (Grid layout).

My question is product row height not equal. So products are not display as a row in my site. As a solution I would like to divide product grid layout row by row.

Something like that:
http://prnt.sc/ezw0t4

Sample page URL:
http://kitchengallery.lk/all-products/commercial-kitchen-equipments/

Please let me know if you guys have any idea to do this.
Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION 1 : FLEXBOX**

Using a **flexbox model** should do the job. Reference for below code.

Equal height columns - [Codepen](https://codepen.io/imohkay/pen/gpard)

```css
* {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 
 box-sizing: border-box; 
}

html, body  { 
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 150%;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.paddingBlock {
 padding: 20px 0;
}

.eqWrap {
 display: flex;
}

.eq {
 padding: 10px;
}

.eq:nth-of-type(odd) {
 background: yellow;
}

.eq:nth-of-type(even) {
 background: lightblue;
}

.equalHW {
 flex: 1;
}

.equalHMWrap {
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.equalHM {
 width: 32%;
}

.equalHMRWrap {
 justify-content: space-between;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.equalHMR {
 width: 32%;
 margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.equalHMVWrap {
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.equalHMV {
 width: 32%;
 margin: 1%; 
}

.equalHMV:nth-of-type(3n) {
 margin-right: 0; 
}

.equalHMV:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
 margin-left: 0; 
}
```

```html
<div class="paddingBlock">
  <h1>EQUAL HEIGHT COLUMNS</h1>
  <p>Simply add display:flex to the parent</p>
  <div class="equalHWrap eqWrap">
    <div class="equalH eq">boo <br> boo</div>
    <div class="equalH eq">shoo</div>
    <div class="equalH eq">clue</div>
  </div>
</div>            

<div class="paddingBlock">
  <h1>EQUAL HEIGHT + WIDTH COLUMNS</h1>
  <p>Add display:flex to the parent and flex:1 to the boxes</p>
  <div class="equalHWrap eqWrap">
    <div class="equalHW eq">boo <br> boo</div>
    <div class="equalHW eq">shoo</div>
    <div class="equalHW eq">clue</div>
  </div>
</div>            

<div class="paddingBlock">
  <h1>EQUAL HEIGHT + WIDTH COLUMNS WITH MARGINS</h1>
  <p>Add display:flex, justify-content: space-between; to the parent and give a width to the boxes that totals to less than 100%. E.g. These boxes have a width of 32% each. The remaining width of 4% (i.e. 32 x 3 = 96%) will be used to create the space between the boxes and simulate margins. No need to remove margins on the first and last child!</p>
  <div class="equalHMWrap eqWrap">
    <div class="equalHM eq">boo <br> boo</div>
    <div class="equalHM eq">shoo</div>
    <div class="equalHM eq">clue</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="paddingBlock">
  <h1>EQUAL HEIGHT COLUMNS WITH MARGINS IN MULTIPLE ROWS</h1>
  <p>Building on the above example, just give bottom margins to the boxes. Add a flex-wrap: wrap to the parent, so that boxes go to the next line when they run out of space in a 'row'.</p>
  <div class="equalHMRWrap eqWrap">
    <div class="equalHMR eq">boo</div>
    <div class="equalHMR eq">shoo</div>
    <div class="equalHMR eq">clue</div>
    <div class="equalHMR eq">boo <br> boo </div>
    <div class="equalHMR eq">shoo</div>
    <div class="equalHMR eq">clue</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="paddingBlock">
  <h1>EQUAL HEIGHT COLUMNS WITH MARGINS IN MULTIPLE ROWS and VARIABLE NO OF BOXES</h1>
  <p>Add display:flex, flex-wrap: wrap to the parent and give a width to the boxes. Give margins to the boxes and remove the left and right margins of the first and last box in each 'row' using the nth-of-type selector. Unlike the previous example, justify-content: space-between on the parent does not work for an uneven number of boxes, because if there are five boxes in all, the third and fifth will align to the left and right of the perceived 'row'.</p>
  <div class="equalHMVWrap eqWrap">
    <div class="equalHMV eq">boo <br> boo</div>
    <div class="equalHMV eq">shoo</div>
    <div class="equalHMV eq">clue</div>
    <div class="equalHMV eq">boo <br> boo </div>
    <div class="equalHMV eq">clue</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**SOLUTION 2: JAVASCRIPT**

If browser support is an issue for you then instead of going for flexbox I would recommend that you **use JavaScript or jQuery to loop through all the columns** in a row, find the column with maximum height in that row and then apply it to all the columns in that row.

Something like this:

```
function relPostHeight(){
    var imgheightArray = [],
        headheightArray = [];
    $("#related-posts .row .col-sm-3").each(function(){
        var imgheight = $(this).find('.featured-image img').height();
        var headheight = $(this).find('.entry-header').height();
        imgheightArray.push(imgheight);
        headheightArray.push(headheight);
    });
    var minimageHeight = Math.max.apply(Math, imgheightArray);
    var minheadHeight = Math.max.apply(Math, headheightArray);
    $("#related-posts .featured-image").css({'min-height': minimageHeight});
    $("#related-posts .entry-header").css({'min-height': minheadHeight});
}

relPostHeight();
$(window).on('resize', relPostHeight);
```

Answer (score 1):

Specifically, for woocommerce columns to be all equal in height across the row, we need to convert the old block-style CSS to a flex layout. Here is all the CSS you need to add:

```
.woocommerce ul.products {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.woocommerce ul.products li.product {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.woocommerce ul.products li.product a {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
   flex-direction: column;
}
.woocommerce ul.products li.product a:first-child {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.woocommerce ul.products li.product .button {
  margin: 1rem auto;
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
```